# Show littleproxy log in JavaFX UI

Tags: java, javafx, proxy

I want to display Littleproxy logs (incoming and outgoing traffic) in JavaFX UI,is there any way to do this?

```
  HttpProxyServer server = DefaultHttpProxyServer.bootstrap()
            .withAddress(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8080)).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC LittleProxy use Log4J for its logging. You could try following this
[JavaFX log4j TextArea log appender](http://www.rshingleton.com/javafx-log4j-textarea-log-appender/)

Comment: I really appreciate it,But are you sure littleproxy uses Log4j?

Comment: Taken from the project GitHub page (https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy): 
"For examples of configuring logging, see src/test/resources/log4j.xml."
Now I'm sure :)

Comment: Thank you so much,

Comment: It was my first time to worked with Log4j , Finally I add 'log4j2.xml' to my project but there is no any traffic log in console ! Is there any other tricky step that I have to perform?

Comment: For troubleshooting your logging code it'll probably be better to start a new question to give more info about your configuration and code. For now I'm afraid I can only say that you should get familiar with log4j and try to get some Hello world logging to work first. After that it should be easier hooking up LittleProxy to your own log.